# Will deleting modules from node_modules and then pasting it again will work?

Tags: node.js, web-deployment

I am new to nodejs . I am currently having a project which is quite big and uses private packages too. will deleting any package from node_modules and pasting it again cause any harm to my project? Also when deplyoing to server, i did some mistake and the structure is different as that of my local. Example in my local i have packages installed on the same level of the project and also inside but on the server , packages are only installed inside the project. I am kindof scared if i push the code to server, it might crash and many are using the api's in it.

Comment: Your projects _package.json_ keeps track of all dependencies, so every module under _node_modules_ correlates to a dependency in your _package.json_, as a direct or indirect dependency. You could simply delete your _node_modules_ folder and use `npm install` to download all dependent modules again if you screwed something up under _node_modules_.

Answer (score 1):

First of all , deleting package from node_modules and then pasting them again will not affect your project, for the second part of your question if you are using public node modules you have not to push them to your git/svn repository Only be sure that you added all the dependencies to the package.json file and the in the server re-install the packages using npm install

Comment: thanks...but i am also using private packages which are inside the node_modules...i might be making changes to private packages in future ..so what best can i do?

Comment: you can include only the private modules to git/svn repository. and after  if you change this module locally just push it and then update your project in the server

Comment: i have include **/node_modules/** in .gitignore and inside node_modules is my private repo.. named @renil . what should i write in .gitignore.?

Comment: Well i think you should add the following line to your gitignore file:

!/node_modules/your_private_module_name 

I should work.